# DataTable.js exports .xlsx.zip instead of .xlsx Excel file only when using Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, firefox, datatables

I am using DataTable.js for exporting my data table content. When I use browsers like Chrome or Explorer exporting of Excel file works well. I get .xlsx file extension.
But when I use Mozilla Firefox I get .xlsx.zip file. Does anyone knows why is this happening on this specific browser?

This is a part of code for exporting Excel files:

```
buttons: [
{
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    title: $('body').find('h2').text(),
    text: '<div title="Excel"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i></div>',
    exportOptions: {
        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        format: {
            body: function (a, b, row) {
                // Strip $ from salary column to make it numeric
                return exportData(a, b);
            }
        }
    },
    header: true,
    download: 'download',
    orientation: 'landscape'
}]
```

It basically sees .xlsx as part of title.

Comment: Not a duplicate but related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027539/datatables-export-to-excel-downloading-a-zip-file

Comment: What version are you using? It has been fixed in buttons 1.3.1 see https://github.com/DataTables/Buttons/issues/67

Comment: @davidkonrad Oh, that could be it. I am using v1.0, I will try to upgrade it and see if the problem still exists. Thank you!